# Webpart error while connecting SharePoint 2010 with CRM 2011

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm-2011, bcs

I'm using [Girish Raja's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishr/archive/2011/05/16/source-code-from-my-teched-osp309-session.aspx) MSDN blog reference when creating a BDCM to connect my SP 2010 and CRM 2011. I'm able to complete all steps mentioned in the document except the last one. The issues I am facing,

1. I'm not able to create an External List from the SP web interface (All Site Content --> Create --> External List). I'm forced to create it from SPD. Any particular reason behind it?
2. After I create the External List from SPD, the list doesnt show up in the browser. Gives me this error msg when i open the list.

`"Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator"`

On checking the ULS logs, it tell me there is some exception in the `CRMEntityService.SharePoint.Connector.CRMOnlineConnector.ExecuteStatic` method. Have uploaded the ULS logs here on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vVV5TZqG).

The CRMProxy service is running fine. What else could be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that your CRM return more then 2000 elements. Is that right?
Because by default only 2000 elements can display by using BCS/BDC.
If you want to show more then 2000 elements you have to change the throttling settings for this service application.

Try the following post. This one describe how to change the throttling settings of the bdc service application

http://msscorner.de/en/2011/12/19/sharepoint-bcs-unable-to-display-this-web-part/

I hope it helps.